# Raw HTML inside v-model inside vuejs template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, icons, radio-group, bootstrap-vue

In my application, I would like to use standard bootstrap-vue radio buttons.  Along the side of the text I would like to put a small icon. During the prototyping phase, when I was using JS and CSS from CDN I came up with this solution which was satisfying for me:

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mode: 'trx',
    mode_options: [
      { text: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> UP', value: 'up' },
      { text: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i> DOWN', value: 'down' }
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" >
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <b-form-radio-group id="btnradios_mode"
                            buttons
                            v-model="mode"
                            button-variant="outline-secondary"
                            :options="mode_options"
                            name="radiosBtnDefault" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I started to move towards the production version and I used VUE-CLI with templates, the same code does not work: the icons do not show up. While trying to understand the problem, I started to suspect some issue with the way how the RAW HTML is handled inside v-model (v-* in general) but I'm not able to fully understand/debug the problem.

Would anyone suggest a workaround? For me, another way of embedding icons inside a radio group would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-form-radio-group id="btnradios_mode"
                            buttons
                            v-model="mode"
                            button-variant="outline-secondary"
                            name="radiosBtnDefault" >
            <b-form-radio v-for="opt in mode_options" :key="opt.value" :value="opt.value">
                <i :class="opt.icon"/>
                {{ opt.text }}
            </b-form-radio>
        </b-form-radio-group>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                mode: 'trx',
                mode_options: [
                    { icon: 'fas fa-cloud-upload-alt', text: 'UP', value: 'up' },
                    { icon: 'fas fa-cloud-download-alt', text: 'DOWN', value: 'down' }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I was looking for.